# Cyclic group - Prove that subgroup generated by x is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I don't know how to prove the following:

Let $(G,\Delta)$ a group and $x\in G$. Prove that the subgroup generated by $x$, $<x>=\{x^k / k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What is there to prove? That a subgroup is subgroup? Or are you required in your homework to prove this by checking the axioms of a subgroup? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one step-subgroup test.

If H is a nonempty subset of a group G such that if $a,b \in H$ then $ab^{-1} \in H$. Then H is a subgroup.

(I leave the proof of the above to you (simply check the axioms of being a group))

First we note that since $x \in \langle x \rangle$ so it is not empty.

Next if $a,b \in \langle x \rangle$, say $a=x^n, b=x^m$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we show that $ab^{-1} \in \langle x \rangle$. But of course this is true as $ab^{-1} = x^{n-m}$ and $ n-m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why do you do $x^{n}.x^{m}=x^{n+m}$? In no place it says that the operation $\Delta$ is the multiplication. I'm sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: its not that it is multiplication it is just that I am applying whatever is the operation n or m times and denote it $x^n$.